# Closed and complete

Tags: general-topology

Prove that closed $\Longleftrightarrow$ complete for all subsets of $\mathbb{C}$.

Ok so I know I saw a proof that complex numbers are complete. The proof is in my book so I know I don't need to show that in my proof. I guess I don't know how to word this. If I assume I have a space that is complete well then I know it is closed because complete subspaces are closed. What else can I do here?

Comment: State your definition of closed.  State your definition of complete.  Identify the gap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is straightforward to show that a closed subset of a complete metric space is itself complete (if $x_n$ is Cauchy it has a limit $x$ in the ambient space, and $x$ must lie in the closed subset, hence the closed subset is complete) , so this gives one direction.

Now suppose $A$ is a complete subset of $\mathbb{C}$, and suppose $x_n \to x$, with $x_n \in A$. Since $x_n$ is Cauchy, it has a limit $y\in A$, and since the limit is unique, we have $y=x$, hence $x \in A$ and so $A$ is closed.

Answer (score 0):

If $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}$ is closed and we have $ \{ z _{n} \} \subset \Omega$ a Cauchy sequence, then $ \{ z _{n} \} \subset \Omega$ is contained in a closed ball, but a closed ball in $\mathbb{C} $ is compact. A compact metric space is sequentially compact, so there is a subsequence $ \{ z _{n_{k}} \} \subset \Omega$ converging in $\Omega$.

But if a Cauchy sequence has a convergent subsequence, then the whole sequence converges to the same limit.

Comment: Compactness is unnecessary. Completeness is enough. The claim holds in general for any complete metric space.